# Nginx routing on IP address

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have my domain example.com, so when someone hits on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or example.com the request is automatically directed to https://example.com - which works fine. However, when I use IP address of the node app 1.2.3.4 it doesn't route to https://example.com which is SSL enabled. If I use the IP address, it shows me the same page but without the padlock icon.

So how do I route a request to https://example.com when someone enters the IP address of node app?

My Node JS APP is hosted on AWS EC2 instance, I have also installed ssl using certbot (LetsEncrpyt). This is my nginx file.

```
 events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
 
  include    conf/mime.types;
  include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  include    /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
  index    index.html index.htm;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   logs/access.log  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts


# Settings for normal server listening on port 80
server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  listen       [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
  # location / {
  # }
  # Redirect non-https traffic to https
  if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
server {
  listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SSL will not work for IP because certificate is issued for the domain name (hence no padlock icon)

You can listen for IP on port 80 (default HTTP port) and redirect to https://example.com

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
   return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```